# Backbone.js architecture: routes or application state?

Tags: architecture, backbone.js, routes

I'm building a Backbone.js app that will be fairly complex. Coming from a Rails background, I'm trying to figure out when it's appropriate to trigger routes (and their functions with the true option), and when to just change application state without affecting the url.

It seems like relying heavily on the routers would be a good direction because I can easily launch the application into any state I'd like. Are there any best practices on this? When I started relying on the navigate method I noticed my views were getting duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS mentioned above by Jsonwyatt . His statement "It really depends on the situation" is appropriately correct. Something like state change or state manipulation is generally what I prefer is via views . However in a case for example like where I actually navigate through any Navigation urls I would prefer something like `/home/foo` to be rendered via backbone router.

But when you are actually just stating a model state change like updating a model. You can just do `model.save()` instead of driving through a url something like `/home/student/1` which unnecessarily woulkd render another view . But that might cause you to render another view which could have been done from inside your present view only .

For reference Darik bailey had a very good talk on application states and router navigation and maintaning browser history pushstate talk on this. For reference you can go through this link .

[dont execute a backbone js route handler from your code](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/)

Comment: Another great article from Derick! That was the exact problem and progression I've been working through. I needed a way to update the application state identically through events and routing, this does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the situation.

You typically want to use routes when the state actually **is** something you'd want to be able to bookmark/share.

On the other hand, if you're just updating something in the view and it's not really something you would need to retrieve the state for - just change it. However, you could provide an option for a route to the state, but not require it. For example, if your app involves maps - you may not want to update the location/route every time the user pans/zooms the map, but it might be a good idea to provide a button for "share" or "bookmark"-type functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! I think my question was a little vague. This article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078627/backbone-js-architecture-routes-or-application-state) is exactly what I was looking for, and what I'd been experiencing.